tcolorbox: title and subtitle without linebreak (detach title)
I would like to have a tcolorbox with a title and a subtitle (each followed by a colon ':'), all in the same color (red), but without linebreak: 

with
detach title,% title without linebreak  
before upper=\textcolor{red}{\tcbtitle:~}, % colon ':' does not become red.....

I get this for the title; but what do I have to do for the subtitle?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=My Title,
fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
coltitle=red,
detach title,% title without linebreak  
before upper=\textcolor{red}{\tcbtitle:~},
%
before lower = \tcbsubtitle{My Subtitle:},
subtitle style = {
colback=black!5!white,% tcolorbox default
boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
},
% optinally:
lower separated = false,% no dashed line
sharp corners,
]
Upper Text.
\tcblower
Lower Text.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}


\tcbtitle is the formatted form of the title. You can replace it with \textcolor{red}{\sffamily\bfseries\tcbtitletext:} to get the colon colored.

Thanks. I edited before upper=\textcolor{red}{\tcbtitle:~}, Else maybe better to use the tcb-keys as far as possible. My main problem is the "linebreak"

Not related: frame hidden option has no effects on tcolorboxes using standard skin.

\tcbsubtitle is designed to take a full line and making it detached is ... tricky.
Life would be much easier (and even a bit quicker) if you are willing to define your own commands like \mytitle and \mysubtitle which apply the desired font and color selection.
In the following example, the output of the second box using \mytitle and \mysubtitle is shorter because the lower part of the first box using (detached) \tcbsubtitle has some default upper and lower paddings inherited from outer tcolorbox.
PS: Quite some advanced config of tcolorbox needs a mechanism to retrieve the value of some "property" of a tcolorbox. But it's impossible for now, without making use of internal macros and registers. Currently only the color is retrievable, see use of tcbcoltitle color in the second box.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=My Title,
  fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
  coltitle=red,
  detach title,% title without linebreak  
  before upper=\tcbtitle,
  % append ":~" to the title text
  after title={:~},
  before lower = \tcbsubtitle{My Subtitle:~},
  subtitle style = {
    colback=black!5!white,% tcolorbox default
    boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
    % make \tcbsubtitle typeset like a \tcbox
    capture=hbox,
    on line,
    after={},
    % cancel the effect of "/tcb/oversize" on right side
    enlarge right by=0pt,
    right=0pt,
  },
  % optinally:
  lower separated = false,% no dashed line
  sharp corners,
]
Upper Text.
\tcblower
Lower Text.
\end{tcolorbox}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mytitlestyle}{}{\sffamily\bfseries\color{tcbcoltitle}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mytitle}{}{{\mytitlestyle\tcbtitletext:~}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mysubtitle}{m}{{\mytitlestyle#1:~}}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=My Title,
  fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
  coltitle=red, % this is retrievable from color name "tcbcoltitle"
  detach title,% title without linebreak  
  before upper=\mytitle,
  before lower = \mysubtitle{My Subtitle},
  % optinally:
  lower separated = false,% no dashed line
  sharp corners,
]
Upper Text.
\tcblower
Lower Text.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}



I understand. Very good!
